# Java List - How to get the column values of a multi dimensional List?

Tags: java, list, collections

I really need some help. I have a List which has 4 columns and 4 rows. I did something like this:

```
if(list.size()!=0){
 Iterator it = list.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(it.next().toString());
 }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
 System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

but both has the same result:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@58e6b9bc
[Ljava.lang.Object;@13ac133d
[Ljava.lang.Object;@62313e2
[Ljava.lang.Object;@68ee5d93
```

I have no problem with one dimensional List but with multidimensional I really have headache. Please help.

Comment: You should show the code that fills the `list`.

Comment: Do you have a List in your List or some arbitrary object? Are you going to print it out or what do you have in mind?

Comment: I wanna print it out. The values from the list are from the database table.

Comment: Looks like it might be a list of arrays of objects.  Can you confirm?  If that's the case, you probably want to iterate through each array, within the loop that iterates through the list.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yeah... Harry Joy just answered it but thanks for all you guys who are enthusiastic to help a beginner like me.

Comment: Yes, looks like he typed his answer while I was typing my comment.  Happens a lot on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your list contains Object Array as elements.

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@58e6b9bc
```

This means the Object you are trying to print is array. To get complete content of list you have to also iterate over this object arrays (each element of list). Try this:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
 Object[] objArr = (Object[]) list.get(i);
 for(Object obj: objArr){
    System.out.println(obj);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude... It worked. I'm kinda new to this thing. Huh.. Java has such steep learning curve.

Comment: @Whoever down voted: I have no problem with down vote but you should also case to tell me my mistake so I can improve it next time.

Comment: This is interesting. How do you know that it is an array? I wish to know.

Comment: @edem When something like this: `[Ljava.lang.Object;@58e6b9bc` prints on console we can assume that it's an array.

Answer (score 2):

I think your List contains an array of another list. You have to add another loop.

```
for(Object []ar:list)
 {
   for(Object ele:ar)
    {
     System.out.println(ele);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a List in your List then it will work this way:

```
        for (List<TypeOfYourObjectHere> element : list) {
            for (Object subElement : element) {
                System.out.println(subElement);
            }
        }
```

if its an array then:

```
    for (TypeOfYourObjectHere[] element : list) {
        for (Object subElement : element) {
            System.out.println(subElement);
        }
    }
```

Please note that if you don't have an iterable object in your outer list than you have to think about some other way like overriding the `toString()` method.

It would help help too if you have told us what did you want to achieve.

Comment: I don't think 1st case is possible cause If it was then it might be printed like `[elements in list]` but it's not printed like that so it might not be the list in the list case.

Comment: I tried it out so it works. I always try out code before posting.

Comment: I'm not blaming your code just notifying that it doesn't seems that it's list inside a list.